# Azure Dataflow - Resource references resources which could not be loaded

Tags: datasource, transformation, azure-synapse

I have a set of pipelines, dataflows and a trigger, that when validated show the error message: This resource references resources which could not be loaded. This occured after manually merging a feature branch to the develop and main branches. See below:

[Workspace validation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc4st.png)

**Example pipeline below**
{
"name": "NewListingToStaging",
"properties": {
"activities": [
{
"name": "Transform for Insert",
"type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
"timeout": "0.00:10:00",
"retry": 1,
"retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
"secureOutput": false,
"secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
"dataflow": {
"referenceName": "TransformListingForInsert",
"type": "DataFlowReference"
},
"integrationRuntime": {
"referenceName": "cc-integration-large-compute",
"type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
},
"traceLevel": "Fine",
"runConcurrently": true
}
}
],
"folder": {
"name": "Rex CRM/Listings/Workers"
},
"annotations": []
}
}

I have fixed the names of several code sections to ensure the output name matches the input name of the next section e.g. [flatten1] because they were different in a few places due to the code merge. Also I checked that referenced resources existed in the code base. Despite this the code is still not valid. Also I compared the code with previous versions of the code base where possible and found no indication as to the cause of the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

> This resource references resources which could not be loaded

***This error typically arises when essential resources, such as datasets, linked services, or dataflows, are absent within the Azure Data Factory (ADF) environment. It indicates a discrepancy between the referenced components and their availability within the ADF infrastructure.***

**To resolve the issue, you can follow below steps:**

- Please do a manual verification to ensure the existence of all resources, including datasets, linked services, integration runtimes, dataflows, etc.
- If any fork branch is functioning correctly, comparing the two JSON would be beneficial.

This process aims to confirm the availability and functionality of each component within the ADF.